# Trying to get Win32_BIOS version by using a path string

Tags: c#, wmi

I am racking my brain on how to do this. I found a link about 2 months ago that showed how to get a single element from a wmi call.

```
class Sample
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        ManagementObject o =
            new ManagementObject("Win32_Service.Name='Alerter'");

        //or with a full path :

        ManagementObject mObj =
            new ManagementObject(
            "\\\\MyServer\\root\\MyApp:MyClass.Key='abc'");

        return 0;
    }
}
```

which i thought was awesome because it returns results a lot faster than by doing a complete search through WMI to get 1 property. I fiddled around with it and got this code to work with Win32_ComputerSystem and I think i even got it to work with Win32_DiskDrive and maybe BaseBoard but i can't remember off the top of my head since i can't find that particular bit of code. So now I am trying to get it to work with Win32_BIOS and keep striking out. I can't seem to find the "key" property so that it will return a valid result.

I have tried the following paths to no avail.

```
\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_BIOS.SoftwareElementState=3
\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_BIOS.TargetOperatingSystem=0
\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_BIOS.SoftwareElementState=3,TargetOperatingSystem=0
```

the 2 keys that i find in the Win32_BIOS class are Name and Version.. but version is what i need. Since i'm trying to get this on different computers I can't just hard code a name in and can't find a alternative way to get the BIOS name. So i guess i'm kinda stuck for a minute. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the WMI Code Creator? http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8572

Comment: @Tergiver thank you for that link, it was useful. Nice to see this program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WMI object path which you are looking for is formed by the Name, SoftwareElementID, SoftwareElementState,  TargetOperatingSystem and Version properties.

And look like this

```
Win32_BIOS.Name="Ver 1.00 BIOS A05 PARTTBL",SoftwareElementID="Ver 1.00 BIOS A05 PARTTBL",SoftwareElementState=3,TargetOperatingSystem=0,Version="DELL   - 6040000"
```

If you want to know which if the object path of a specific instance you can use a tool like the [Wmi delphi code creator](http://code.google.com/p/wmi-delphi-code-creator/).

[image]

Comment: So i guess I saw this in my debug editor, but i just didn't want to believe it because I would have like to have used Win32_bios. ohwell. guess i have to stick with embedded controllers only.

Answer (score 0):

We use WMI to enumerate network interface info across the LAN.  Here is a pared down set of code that will do what you want.  You can see that substituting computer name is easy.  Also, if you query across the LAN to different computers you will need to supply credentials in the 
ConnectionOptions object.

```
String path = @"\\{0}\ROOT\CIMV2";
String BiosVersion = String.Empty;

ConnectionOptions co = new ConnectionOptions();
ManagementScope scope = 
    new ManagementScope(String.Format(path, "."), co);

scope.Connect();

ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS");
ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

ManagementObjectCollection moc = search.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
{
    BiosVersion = (String)mo["SMBIOSBIOSVersion"];
}
```

Comment: I dont want to use a ManagementObjectSearcher. I'm not trying to do this over a network but rather locally on individual computers. The time it takes a searcher class and a foreach loop is significant enough on these computers that we use that I can't afford to use it. Thank you though for your suggestion.